# Codename One - clickButtonByLabel("OK");

Tags: codenameone

The following test runs well in the Simulator. On an Android device, instead, it seems to stop before the first `clickButtonByLabel("OK")`: I mean that `clickButtonByLabel("English")` is executed, after that the picker is opened, but the "ok" button of the picker is not clicked (on a real Android device, instead in the simulator is clicked). The `waitForUnnamedForm();` is inserted by the Test Recorder, I guess that is the wait for the picker form.

The fact that in the picker the default value is selected (because no other one is selected) is intentional.

What's wrong?

```
public class ChangeLanguage extends AbstractTest {
    public boolean runTest() throws Exception {
        waitForFormName("Login-Form");
        clickButtonByLabel("English");
        waitForUnnamedForm();
        clickButtonByLabel("OK");
        waitFor(1000);
        waitForFormName("Login-Form");
        assertLabel("Different language? Select:");
        clickButtonByLabel("English");
        waitForUnnamedForm();
        selectInList(new int[]{0}, 3);
        clickButtonByLabel("OK");
        waitFor(1000);
        waitForFormName("Login-Form");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you run it on an up to date Android skin?

It's possible that "English" becomes "ENGLISH" on the device due to the [caps mode](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/factional-padding-margin-rounded-border-ripple-caps-google-connect.html).

Comment: I analyzed the flow of the test adding some logs... the problem is the method clickButtonByLabel(String text), because its istruction "b.released();" on the Button with label "OK" doesn't return (blocking the test). Instead "b.released();" on the button with label "English" returns correctly.
I wasn't able to fix the bug.